# Prove that a probability measure on $\mathcal{B}[0,1]$ and lebesgue measure are mutually singular

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

could someone help me with the next problem.
Let $f$ be the (increasing, continuous) Cantor function and let $\mu$ be the probability measure on
$\mathcal{B}[0,1]$ with distribution function $f$. Show that $\mu \perp \lambda$.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\lambda (C)=0$ and $\mu (C^{c})=0$ where $C is the Cantor set.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to prove that